# Best approach to group the differences between each row by month, year, etc?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
Index                                  Diff
2019-03-14 11:32:21.583000+00:00       0
2019-03-14 11:32:21.583000+00:00       2
2019-04-14 11:32:21.600000+00:00       13
2019-04-14 11:32:21.600000+00:00       14
2019-05-14 11:32:21.600000+00:00       19
2019-05-14 11:32:21.600000+00:00       27
```

What would be the best approach to group by the month and take the difference inside of those months?

Using the `.diff()` option I am able to find the difference between each row, but I am trying to use the `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))` with no success.

Expected Output:

```
    Index                       Diff
0   2019-03-31 00:00:00+00:00   2.0
1   2019-04-30 00:00:00+00:00   1.0
2   2019-05-31 00:00:00+00:00   8.0
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: And what is the output supposed to look like?

Comment: I would like to get a sum of the differences by month, year, etc. 
i.e. March: 2, April: 1, May: 8

Comment: @martba17 based off your comment I have edited your post to include an expected output and answered. If there is anything particular about the expected output that is incorrect, then please edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether or not your date is on the index, you can comment out `df1 = df.reset_index()`. Also, check that your index is in `DateTimeIndex` format if it is on the index. If not in the correct format, then you can change the data type with `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`. Then, you should be set to change the `Diff` column with `df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Index', freq='M'))['Diff'].diff()` and then later groupby with the full dataframe:

input:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Diff': {'2019-03-14 11:32:21.583000+00:00': 2,
  '2019-04-14 11:32:21.600000+00:00': 14,
  '2019-05-14 11:32:21.600000+00:00': 27}})
df.index.name = 'Index'
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

code:

```
df1 = df.reset_index()
df1['Diff'] = df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Index', freq='M'))['Diff'].diff()
df1 = df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Index', freq='M'))['Diff'].max().reset_index()
df1
```

output:

```
    Index                       Diff
0   2019-03-31 00:00:00+00:00   2.0
1   2019-04-30 00:00:00+00:00   1.0
2   2019-05-31 00:00:00+00:00   8.0
```